# Como manipular atributo Date vindo de um resultado Json em Python

Tags: python, json, google

Tenho uma saída Json que estou utilizando em uma Planilha Google Sheets, e com estas informações preciso ordena-las por Data, então preciso fazer com que esta data chegue na planilha Data e Hora separados assim:

Pergunta como realizar um split nesta date data: "2019-07-22T16:00:04.8579075" e transforma-la em Data e Hora como abaixo

**Data 22/07/2019**

**Hora 16:00**

```
[
    {
        ordemChegadaId: 1,
        data: "2019-07-22T16:00:04.8579075",
        veiculoId: 29,
        nome: "J G DO VALE - TRANSPORTES ME"
    },
    {
        ordemChegadaId: 2,
        data: "2019-07-22T16:30:02.8375000",
        veiculoId: 29,
        nome: "AVES - TRANSPORTES ME"
    },
    . . .
]
```

Script Python responsável em enviar às informações para o Google Sheets

```
function IMPORTJSON(url){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined")
    {
      return "Node Not Available";
    } 
    else if(typeof(json) === "object")
    {
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json)
      {
        //datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-05-29T19:30:03.283Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        tempArr.push([json[obj].data, json[obj].ordem, json[obj].veiculoId, json[obj].getVeiculo.motorista]);

      }
      return tempArr;
    } 
    else if(typeof(json) !== "object") 
    {
      return json;
    }


  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

Comment: você sabe que esse script aí é Javascript, não é Python, né? Eu estava elaborando uma resposta com Python aqui, as respostas que já existem estão incompletas, mas também são Python. Se você não puder mudar onde está usando o script, não vão adiantar.

Answer (score 0):

converter a data do JSON pode fazer conforme o código abaixo.
Deixei para esplicar nos comentários do código e não aqui na resposta para ficar mais fácil o entendimento.

```
import json;
import datetime;

dados = '{"ordemChegadaId": 1,"data": "2019-07-22T16:15:04.8579075", "veiculoId": 29, "nome": "J G DO VALE - TRANSPORTES ME"}';
//Aqui estou transformando a String dados em um objeto JSON 
dadosJsonFormat = json.loads(dados);

dateTimeStr = dadosJsonFormat["data"];
//Como a data que veio no JSON vem como string então precisamos converter de string para datetime.
dateTimeObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateTimeStr[0:-1], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f');
//Depois de convertido para datetime é só utilizar o método format para criar a data e hora
data = '{}/{}/{}'.format(dateTimeObj.day,dateTimeObj.month,dateTimeObj.year);
hora = '{}:{}'.format(dateTimeObj.hour,dateTimeObj.minute);

print(data,hora);
```

**Importante**
Repare que na hora de converter a string para datetime eu utilizei `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f` para mapear a sua string, veja que separando a data da hora no seu JSON vem o caractere **T** e entra os segundos e milésimos de segundo vem o caractere **.** , eles precisam estar nesse mapeamento também.
Outro detalhe é que no seu JSON o campo de milésimos de segundo esta vindo com 7 posições e a função `strptime` aceita no máximo 6 nesse parâmetro, por isso tive que remover o último com o código `dateTimeStr[0:-1]`

Pode testar esse código utilizando o site [repl.it](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/Converter-string-de-data-recebida-de-um-JSON)

**EDITADO**
Aqui está o código utilizando somente o regx
Não precisacolocar o import json no seu código, pois vc já tem a sua variável json que tem esse conteúdo, só utilize do `dateTimeStr = dadosJsonFormat["data"];` pra baixo.

```
import json;

dados = '{"ordemChegadaId": 1,"data": "2019-07-22T16:15:04.8579075", "veiculoId": 29, "nome": "J G DO VALE - TRANSPORTES ME"}';

dadosJsonFormat = json.loads(dados);

dateTimeStr = dadosJsonFormat["data"];

data = '{}/{}/{}'.format(dateTimeStr[8:10],dateTimeStr[5:7],dateTimeStr[0:4]);
hora = '{}:{}'.format(dateTimeStr[11:13],dateTimeStr[14:16]);

print(data,hora);
```

Comment: Estou usando o editor Google Script pois este script passa estas informações para o Google Sheets e as importações de bibliotecas não funcionam, ai esta o problema, estes import json; import datetime; não consigo adicionar.

Comment: Não é mais fácil usar o [`datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)? Exemplo: `data = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(dateTimeStr[:-1])`

Comment: Então vai precisar usar somente regx, vou editar minha reposta para lhe ajudar

Comment: @Cyberlacs acho que agora você consegue utilizar sem problema, lembrando que aquele import json você não precisa pois você já tem o json, eu tive que utilizar ele para transformar a string em um json.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode formatar com o datetime buit-in do Python e usar o método **strptime(data, formatacao)**

por exemplo: se estiver recebendo um objeto de data -> 2016-09-22

```
from datetime import datetime

data = '2016-09-22'
# pegar os primeiros 10 caracteres e converter 
# para objeto date no formato ano/mes/dia
data_formatada = datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d')
print("Data: ", type(data_formatada)) # Data:  <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```